# Invariant factor decomposition, fundamental theorem of finite generated abelian groups

Tags: finite-groups

We know from the fundamental theorem that every finite group $G$ can be written as $G\cong Z_{n_1}\times\cdots\times Z_{n_t}$, where $n_i| n_{i+1}$.

What is happening in the following example.

$Z_6\cong Z_2\times Z_3$, but 2 does not divide 3.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$. Since there is only one $n_i$, the statement of division is vacuously true.

Comment: I think you mean finite _abelian_ group. Also, $\Bbb Z_6$ _is_ the factorization given by the theorem. In principle you _can_ write $\Bbb Z_1 \times \Bbb Z_6$ if you want it to look like a factorization too, but that might make people cringe, much the same way as saying $1$ is a prime would.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental theorem tells you that **there is at least one** decomposition of $G$ into cyclic groups $\Bbb Z_{n_i}$ such that $n_i\mid n_{i+1}$, it doesn't say that **every** decomposition into cyclic groups is of that form. Since $\Bbb Z_6$ is already a decomposition of itself into cyclic groups, there is no contradiction to the theorem.